# What does the stat() command do on iOS?

Tags: c, ios, filesystems

I see that it correctly returns the root directory as a directory when I pass in '/', but can it be used to detect if a file exists?  Heck, is there even a file system that is accessible to even get at?  Porting some PC code here and wondering if I should just basically assert false on calls like this that assume a file system exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a file system always exists on iOS, but generally the path you want is "/var/mobile/", as anything outside of 'mobile' is out of your domain to read/write to/from.

Generally, however, you are supposed to write files to your sandboxed application's documents directory, which can be gotten like this:

```
// this becomes a char *, if you need NSString, then just remove the UTF8String call.
#define HOME_DIRECTORY [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentsDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] UTF8String]
```

Comment: Ok, a quick followup would be how to drop a file into that space.  If I can do that, my job at unifying architectures gets much easier :)

Comment: Also, where did you find that info so I can go teach myself a bit more?

Comment: Alright, I updated my answer, and I got that info from experience, you can basically read almost any file on the OS, but can't write to anything outside of /var/mobile/ unless you run as root (jail breaking taught me that).

Comment: Lol - Objective C still makes me ill. Still that info is priceless and I can search off those function names to find more.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Now, if I wanted a file to be there on bootup, is there a way to do that, or do I have to go through the NSBundle stuff?

Comment: lets continue this discussion in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5625/discussion-between-richard-ross-and-michael-dorgan